# CSS: Solid border with Panel creates scrollable panel

Tags: css, formborderstyle

I am using Vaadin to create my front-end and when i add the `border-style:solid` to style.css page, i end up with a scrollable v-panel? How can i add the solid style while removing the scrollable option. Please see screenshot for a better explanation.

I have tried to set the `panel.setScrollable(false);` this did not work.

I want to remove the scrolling option from this panel?

Full CSS:

```
v-panel-panelBack{
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:thick;
 border-color:darkgray;

}
```

[image]

Comment: its in development but if your looking for the page source (html) for the frame let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the overflow property should help.

```
overflow: hidden;
```

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/overflow

Comment: i have added that but no change. In vaadin when you add a panel you also get a absoluteLayout, should i be messing with the v-absolutelayout instead of v-panel?

Comment: I'm not familiar with vaadin. overflow its the correct property. Try adding it to each div until the display changes.

Comment: Using your suggestion i have traced it to this class v-panel v-panel-panelBack panelBack. Why cant i change this class?